# How does source MME resolve target MME to send forward relocation request message?

Tags: telecommunication, lte

I am a bit confused here. Can someone please share his/her thoughts on this query ?

Comment: There is no dedicated telecoms Stack Exchange site, unfortunately.  The telecom related tags are expected to apply to programming problems.  The least you could provide is a spec reference.

Answer (score 0):

Once the handover is decided, the source MME sends a Forward Relocation Request to the target MME. 
The method to determine the target MME is based on MME selection functionality in the source MME.

The MME selection function selects an available MME for serving a UE and is based on network topology.

When a MME selects a target MME, the selection function performs a simple load balancing between the possible target MMEs. In networks that deploy dedicated MMEs, e.g. for UEs configured for low access priority, the possible target MME selected by source MME is typically restricted to MMEs with the same dedication.

Refer to the 'MME Selection function' in 23.401 standard of 3GPP.